# How can I display an error dialog in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, joptionpane

I’ve been struggling with creating a Java program which displays a login form.Basically, I want to retreive a database which contains about users and their password. At this moment, I am at the point where I need to display an error message using jOptionPane, but it seems like not working. When I run the file and I click Login button, nothing is displayed.

Here is a part of the code:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   My_Conn conn;
   PreparedStatement st;

   String username=jTextField1.getText();
   String password=String.valueOf(jPasswordField1.getPassword());  

   try {     
      String query="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username=? AND password=? ";
      st=My_Conn.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
      st.setString(1, username);
      st.setString(2, password);

      ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery();
      if(rs.next()) {
         setVisible(false);
         Register reg= new Register();
         reg.setVisible(true);      
      } else {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid Username/ Password");
      }
   } catch (SQLException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it? I mean, maybe your "if is always true" or you are getting an exception?

Comment: The debugger console is displaying this:
debug:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 21 seconds)    

and

Listening on javadebug
User program running
User program finished

Comment: Where did you put breakpoints?

Comment: I place the breakpoint here: `code` private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)

Comment: That strongly suggests the method is not called at all. Please add the code where you add the `ActionListener` to the `JButton`